# use current class without self in python (static method inherit)

Tags: python, inheritance, static-methods

I wondering if there is way to let static method use variable in current class. With that, I can change class action by change member in it.

```py
class A:
    var = 0
    lst = [100, 200, 300]

    @staticmethod
    def static_function():
        print(A.var, A.lst)  # need to indicate current class rather than specific one

    def class_function(self):
        print(self.__class__.var, self.__class__.lst)


class B(A):
    var = 9
    lst = [999, 999, 999]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    B.static_function()   # 0 [100, 200, 300]
    B().class_function()  # 9 [999, 999, 999]
    
    B.static_function()   # what I want: 9 [999, 999, 999]
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a \@classmethod instead of a \@staticmethod

Comment: @khelwood
Oh! Thanks! I found that I mixed the instance method and class method up. and didn't realize the class method is what I want!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your looking for is called a class method, with the syntax:

```py
class A:

    @classmethod
    def class_function(cls):
        print(cls.var, cls.lst)
```

Using this decorator the class iself is passed into the function, the `cls` variable is not a class instance. This produces the results you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose, there is [`@classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod).
Every `classmethod` has an implicit argument that receives the class, often named simply `cls`.

Your method can be transformed in following way:

```py
    @classmethod
    def static_function(cls):
        print(cls.var, cls.lst)
```